# Error saving an Excel File to a shared network drive

Tags: c#, excel, io, network-drive

I am working on a C# Console application which exports a dataset to an excel file and saves the file to a shared network drive using absolute path as follows

```
string fileDestination = @"Z:\Physical DB Dumps\Physical Data\Physical DB Data " + filedate + ".xls";
                if (File.Exists(fileDestination))
                {

                    File.Delete(fileDestination);
                }

                workbook.SaveAs(fileDestination, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                workbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                app.Quit();
```

but for some reasons I could not save the file to the destination and I do not require to provide username and password for the drive as the network drive is always connected to my local machine and can be accessed without the credentials.

Not sure what the issue is. 
**May I know a better way to do this?**

Comment: Did you get any error Message?

Comment: Console itself doesn't give any error but Microsoft Office Upload Center throws me an error saying "Upload Failed"